# Allow Flash videos to run on inappbrowswer for android and iOS

Tags: android, xcode, cordova, flash, ionic-framework

[image]I am currently facing an issue running flash videos on Android and iOS Devices from my ionic app.

I installed the latest archived version of Adobe Flash Player from the following link https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

But, still i get the error
**Adobe Flash Player 9.0.124.0 or above is required**. i have attached the screenshot as well. Is there a solution that will work for both Android and iOS.

I tried running the URL with Photon Flash Browser and it works. But i need a more stable solution.

Thanks

Sourav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is not supported on Android.  It was briefly by an adobe app, but that support ended more than 5 years ago.  FLash in general is pretty much dead, most browsers will not display it by default and even Adobe no longer supports it.  But on mobile it was never really used, the performance was such absolute crap (and on iOS it was against the terms of service at least in the early days).